# The fixed point iteration and find the converge interval

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

I've finished part a, which is quite easy. Can someone gimme some hints on part b and c? Thanks!

Comment: What have you done for part a? And what have you tried for part b and c?

Comment: For part a, I substitute $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ with x, and I get the equation $x = x(2-ax)$, then all we need to do is to solve the equation, which is pretty straightforward. For part b, I set $g(x)= (***)$ and found $g'(x)$ and $g'(x)^2$, then I don't know what to do.

Comment: It would be better if you put that comment into the opening post, so people don't downvote your question.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: Note that $a$ is only true if $x_0 \ne 0$. Otherwise the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n = y_n + \frac 1a$, then find the recursion formula for $y_n$. In this case, you will find it easy to derive a closed formula for $y_n$, which will make answering (b) and (c) easy.

For more general problems, you will find that working with sequences that converge to $0$ is usually easier than those that converge to other values (except $1$ in certain cases). You many not be able find nice closed formulas as here, but it is still easier to make estimations.

**Added**
A small change in the substitution from what I suggest above makes things even easier (one of those improvements one only spots after trying the hard way first): define $y_n = 1 - ax_n$, so $x_n = \frac{1 - y_n}a$. Then $y_n$ satisfies the recursion formula $$\frac{1 -y_{n+1}}a = \frac{1 -y_n}a (2 - (1 - y_n))$$ which reduces to simply $y_{n+1} =y_n^2$. From this it is easy to see that $$y_n = b^{2^n}$$ where $b = y_0$ is the initial pick. Obviously, $y_n$ converges to $0$ when $y_0 \in (-1, 1)$, is a constant $1$ when $y_0 = \pm 1$, and diverges otherwise. I'll leave investigating the speed of convergence to you. Backing out to $x_n$ gives $$x_n = \frac{1 - b^{2^n}}a.$$
In particular, $x_0 = \frac{1 - b}{a}$. $b\in(-1,1)$ corresponds to $x_0 \in (0, 2/a)$. To get a closed interval, shrink the limits in a bit. The speed of convergence for $x_n$ will be the same as for $y_n$.

For (d), if $A$ is invertible, then an almost identical process will work, though you will need to find a substitute condition for $b \in (-1,1)$ (Hint: what well-known condition on matrices tells you if they are invertible?).

I suspect that you are not expected to extend this to non-invertible $A$.

Comment: I followed your answer and found the recursion formula for yn, but still I don't know how to approach part b. What do I do to find the interval and the rate of convergence? Thanks

Comment: From the recusion formula for $y_n$, you can easily deduce a closed formula for $y_n$. I.e. an algebraic formula where $y_n$ depends only on $n$, not on $y_{n-1}$ or other values of $y$. When I have more time than my lunch break, I can add the formula.